# Possible to set libGDX ModelInstance texture coords without creating heap allocations?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have a ModelInstance that I would like to reuse for different stages in my game. Is it possible to call transformUV to change the scale of the texture within the model without directly calling the transformUV method? I want to avoid calling this method as the documentation states that it will cause heap allocations by creating new float arrays. I realise that a simple way around this would be to just create individual ModelInstances, but that seems like a lot more work than simply being able to change parameters within an existing object.